# GIT- Connection closed by ip port 22

Tags: git, networking, ssh

All I was trying to set up a GIT server in my local network and I was trying to clone the repository from my server machine to another machine in my network (the machines I use both are running Windows 10 and Bitvise SSH server)using

```
 git clone username@ip:22/path/to/git/folder/.git
```

while trying to clone I face this error.

```
Connection closed by ip port 22
```

Note: I'm not using a Github, Bitbucket or Gitlab account. I created a local repository in the machine and I was trying to clone the repository to my other system

I'm a newbie and I know that I'm missing something. Your help would so welcome.

Regards!

Comment: Do you have an SSH server running at ip:22? Can you connect to it using `ssh ip`?

Comment: I'm running Bitvise SSH server in server IP:22. I can connect it via putty but not in ssh. I have only administrator account in the server machine and I was trying to access it like `ssh Administrator@IP` and I face the same above error.

Answer (score 0):

> debug1: Connecting to github.com [your ip] port 22.

That does not look like github IP

> debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: Error:  Must authenticate before using this service.
>   That is not SSH identification string.

You are connecting from behind some proxy/firewall that prevents you from using SSH. You should talk with your network administrator.

Or use HTTPS to clone your github repositories.

Cre:https://askubuntu.com/questions/916847/ssh-not-working-connection-closed-by-remote-host

Comment: I was not trying to clone from my GitHub repository. I was trying to clone my local GIT repository to another machine via local network. Help me how to setup HTTPS protocol to my LOCAL GIT.

Comment: this must be a problem you need?https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/

Comment: No, It's not I am facing. I'm not using a public GitHub Repository or Connecting to GitHub Via Internet

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you need to create an ssh key for your account. There are a lot of guides how to do it. Try this solution.